# How to break line in jquery with <br> as a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append in a table a result with a line break that's created dinamically by the code:

```
var linha = adicionarLinhaPeriodo("Período: "+valorPeriodo+"<br>"+" Preço: R$ "+precoPeriodo);
```

But the answer I'm having is:

```
"Período: Até 10 minutos<br> Preço: R$ 4,50"
```

Without the line break!

My whole function code is:

```
 function novoPeriodo() {
  var tabelaCompleta = $("table");
  var valorTitulo = $(".titulo-tabela").val();
  var valorPeriodo = $("#periodo option:selected").text();
  var precoPeriodo = $(".preco-periodo").val();
  var quebraLinha = $("<br>")
  var linha = adicionarLinhaPeriodo("Período: "+valorPeriodo+"<br>"+" Preço: R$ "+precoPeriodo);
  $(".tabela table tbody").each(function(){
    var tabelaId = $(this).attr("id");
    if(valorTitulo==tabelaId){
      linha.find(".fa-trash").click(removeLinha); //Para remover a linha
      $("#"+tabelaId).prepend(linha);
      return linha;
    }
  });
}

function adicionarLinhaPeriodo(periodo,preco) {
  var linha = $("<tr>");
  var colunaTolerancia = $("<td>").text(periodo,preco);
  var colunaEditar = $("<td>");
  var colunaRemover = $("<td>");
  var linkEditar = $("<a>").attr("href","#");
  var linkRemover = $("<a>").attr("href","#");
  var iconeEditar = $("<i>").addClass("fa").addClass("fa-pencil");
  var iconeRemover = $("<i>").addClass("fa").addClass("fa-trash").addClass("ic-remove");
  linkEditar.append(iconeEditar);
  linkRemover.append(iconeRemover);
  colunaEditar.append(linkEditar);
  colunaRemover.append(linkRemover);
  linha.append(colunaTolerancia);
  linha.append(colunaEditar);
  linha.append(colunaRemover);

  return linha;
}
```

Can anybody help me to have the answer of this function in two line inside the  that I'm creating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `html()` method not `text()` method

Change:

```
 var colunaTolerancia = $("<td>").text(periodo,preco);
```

To

```
 var colunaTolerancia = $("<td>").html(periodo,preco);
```